# Создание веб приложения js

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, api, web-apps

Есть задача.
Создать веб приложение которое будет получать данные из Яндекс метрики, яндекс директ, google analytics и google ads по api и формировать csv файл с структурированными данными.

Хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение по поводу плана действий.Как лучше реализовывать и исходя из этого я понял бы, что изучать.

p.s.
Строго не судите, хочется развиваться в подобной автоматизации и задача поставлена самим собой для цели развития. Советам любого рода буду очень рад.

Comment: Мне в свое время сильно помогали скрин-касты на ютубе, на 1-3 часа, где с нуля создается какое-нибудь приложение. Потом отчаянно гуглишь все используемые там библиотеки, технологии, команды, термины... Но главное: повторять за автором, но не след в след, строчка за стройкой, команда за командой. Нет. Посмотрел 3-5-10 минут (в зависимости от опыта и обстоятельств), потом напрягаешь память и стараешься вспомнить, что же автор видео там делал и реализуешь все сам. Затем по аналогии уже начинаешь лучше ориентироваться в том, что самому надо или, хотя бы, какой конкретный вопрос кому задать.

Comment: А использование сторонних API лучше приберечь на потом, в общем случае. Есть много вещей, которые стоит хорошо освоить в первую очередь.